# react-table add edit/delete column

Tags: react-table

I use Rails and React-Table to display tables. It works fine so far. But How can one add an edit/delete column to the React-Table?

Is it even possible?

```
return (
    <ReactTable
      data={this.props.working_hours}
      columns={columns}
      defaultPageSize={50}
      className="-striped -highlight"
    />
    )
```

Comment: You want to add new column where you want to provide edit row data or delete the row. Am I right ?

Comment: @GAJESHPANIGRAHI Do you have any clue on making a cell editable, and then add these buttons?

Comment: @vrosario yes check this link

https://codesandbox.io/s/github/tannerlinsley/react-table/tree/master/archives/v6-examples/react-table-cell-renderers

Comment: you can use this https://www.npmjs.com/package/eprofit

Answer (score 43):

All you need to do is turn `columns` into a component state. You can see a working example https://codesandbox.io/s/0pp97jnrvv

[Updated 3/5/2018] Misunderstood the question, here's the updated answer:

```js
const columns = [
    ...
    {
       Header: '',
       Cell: row => (
           <div>
               <button onClick={() => handleEdit(row.original)}>Edit</button>
               <button onClick={() => handleDelete(row.original)}>Delete</button>
           </div>
       )
    }
]
```

where `handleEdit` and `handleDelete` will be the callbacks how you want to handle the actions when the buttons are clicked.

Comment: As far as I understand your demo, you have a show/hide column function. But I asked for an "edit/delete row" column.

Comment: I had to amend @Rico Chen's answer slightly for the row object to be passed to the callback funtions:

`Cell: ({row}) => (`

Comment: Yes, as @AlasdairShields said, it should be `Cell: ({row}) => (` !

Answer (score 1):

### ReactTable v7

Add a column into a table can be achieved by inserting a **column** object into **columns definitions** that pass into **useTable** hook. Basically, the number of column objects that resides in the columns definitions array represents the number of columns that will be rendered by react-table.

Usually, a minimal column object consists of **Header** and **accessor** which at the Header we pass the name of the column and at the accessor, we pass the key that will be used by the react-table to look up the value from the data passed into **useTable** hook.

```js
{
  Header: "Column Name",
  accessor: "data key",  // can be a nested key
}
```

Here, to render other than a string inside a cell, which is, in this case, is custom button JSX, we can use either **accessor** or **Cell** option and pass to it a **Function** that returns a valid JSX.

### accessor

The [document](https://react-table-v7.tanstack.com/docs/api/useTable#column-options) says that accessor accept either **string** or **Function** Here we use Function to render a JSX button.

```js
accessor: String | Function(originalRow, rowIndex) => any
```

One of the benefits of using **accessor** options is the `rowIndex` is directly available. The **rowIndex** represents the index number of rows inside the data array that is currently managed by `react-table` on the client-side and the **originalRow** is the raw object of **row**.

Here the `rowIndex` can be used as a reference to select and modify row objects in the columns data array.

### Cell

**Cell** option accept **Function** that return either **JSX** or **React.Component**. Cell option is usually used for formatting a cell value, but here we use to render our button.

```js
Cell: Function | React.Component => JSX
```

The **Function** receives **tableInstance** that is quite similar to the result of **useTable** hook with additional **cell**, **row**, and **column** object.

```js
Cell: (tableInstance) => JSX
```

Here we can get the row index information too by destructuring the row object:

```js
Cell: (tableInstance) => {
   const { row: index } = tableInstance;
   return (
      ...
   )
}
```

So, it depends on your requirement in determining whether **accessor** or **Cell** will be the chosen one for rendering your edit/add button. But if you need to get more data/information from *tableIntance*, then **Cell** is the correct option to go.

Note: If you choose **accessor**, please make sure that the **id** is included in the column properties due to the **id** option being required as the document said so.

> Required if accessor is a function.
> This is the unique ID for the column. It is used by reference in things like sorting, grouping, filtering etc.

Now, we already have **the column**. The next is **the button**. Commonly the button is either a **normal button** that will either call a handler for updating a state or triggering a dialog popup or a **link button** that will redirect the app to the detail page.
So, the code will be:

```js
    // accessor
    {
        Header: 'Action',
        id: 'action',
        accessor: (originalRow, rowIndex) => {
            return (
                // you can pass any information you need as argument
                <button onClick={() => onClickHandler(args)}>
                    X
                </button>
            )
        }
    }

    // or Cell
    {
        Header: 'Action',
        accessor: "action",
        Cell: (tableInstance) => {
            const { row: index } = tableInstance;
            return (
                // you can pass any information you need as argument
                <button onClick={() => onClickHandler(args)}>
                    X
                </button>
            )
        }
    }
```

Example:

```js
const { useCallback, useEffect, useMemo, useState } = React;
const { useTable } = ReactTable;

// table data
const data = [
    {
        name: "John",
        workingHours: 40
    },
    {
        name: "Doe",
        workingHours: 40
    }
];

const AddEmployee = ({ onSubmit }) => {
    const [name, setName] = useState("");
    const [workingHours, setWorkingHours] = useState("");

    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        onSubmit(e);
        setName("");
        setWorkingHours("");
    }

    return (
        <fieldset style={{ width: "200px" }}>
            <legend>Add Employee:</legend>
            <form onSubmit={(e) => handleSubmit(e)}>
                <input
                    type="text"
                    name="name"
                    placeholder="Name"
                    value={name}
                    onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
                />
                <br />
                <input
                    type="text"
                    name="workingHours"
                    placeholder="Working Hours"
                    value={workingHours}
                    onChange={(e) => setWorkingHours(e.target.value)}
                />
                <br />
                <button type="submit">Add</button>
            </form>
        </fieldset>
    )
}

const EditEmployee = ({ row, onSave }) => {
    const { originalRow, rowIndex } = row;
    const [name, setName] = useState(originalRow.name);
    const [workingHours, setWorkingHours] = useState(originalRow.workingHours);

    return (
        <fieldset style={{ width: "200px" }}>
            <legend>Edit Employee:</legend>
            <input
                type="text"
                name="name"
                placeholder="Name"
                value={name}
                onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
            />
            <br />
            <input
                type="text"
                name="workingHours"
                placeholder="Working Hours"
                value={workingHours}
                onChange={(e) => setWorkingHours(e.target.value)}
            />
            <br />
            <button onClick={() => onSave({ name, workingHours }, rowIndex)}>Save</button>
        </fieldset>
    )
}

function App() {
    const [tableData, setTableData] = useState(data);
    const [editingRow, setEditingRow] = useState();

    const handleDelete = useCallback((index) => {
        setTableData(tableData.filter((v, i) => i !== index));
    },[tableData]);

    const tableColumns = useMemo(() => [
        {
            Header: 'Name',
            accessor: 'name',
        },
        {
            Header: 'Working Hours',
            accessor: 'workingHours'
        },
        {
            Header: 'Action',
            id: 'action',
            accessor: (originalRow, rowIndex) => {
                return (
                    <div>
                        <button onClick={() => setEditingRow({ originalRow, rowIndex })}>
                            Edit
                        </button>
                        <button onClick={() => handleDelete(rowIndex)}>
                            Delete
                        </button>
                    </div>   
                )
            }
        }
    ], [handleDelete]);

    const {
        getTableProps,
        getTableBodyProps,
        headerGroups,
        rows,
        prepareRow
    } = useTable({
        columns: tableColumns,
        data: tableData,
    });

    const handleSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        const formData = new FormData(event.currentTarget);
        const newData = {};
        formData.forEach((value, key) => newData[key] = value);
        setTableData((prevData) => {
            return [...prevData, newData];
        });
    };

    const handleEdit = useCallback((row, rowIndex) => {
        const editedData = tableData.map((rowData, index) => {
            if (index === rowIndex) {
               return row;
            }
            return rowData;
        });
        setTableData(editedData);
        setEditingRow();
    },[tableData])

    return (
        <div>
            <h3>React-table v.7</h3>
            <br />
            { editingRow ? <EditEmployee row={editingRow} onSave={handleEdit} /> : <AddEmployee onSubmit={handleSubmit} /> }
            <table {...getTableProps()}>
                <thead>
                    {headerGroups.map(headerGroup => (
                        <tr {...headerGroup.getHeaderGroupProps()}>
                            {headerGroup.headers.map(column => (
                                <th {...column.getHeaderProps()}> 
                                    {column.render('Header')}
                                </th>
                            ))}
                    </tr>
                    ))}
                </thead>
                <tbody {...getTableBodyProps()}>
                    {rows.map((row, i) => {
                        prepareRow(row)
                        return (
                            <tr {...row.getRowProps()}>
                                {row.cells.map(cell => {
                                    return (
                                        <td {...cell.getCellProps()}> 
                                            {cell.render('Cell')}
                                        </td>
                                    )
                                })}
                            </tr>
                        )
                    })}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    )
}
 
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('.react'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-table@7.8.0/dist/react-table.development.js"></script>

<div class='react'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can actually add buttons using the accessor prop of the columns in react-table.
here is code example:

```
     {
        Header: 'Action',
        accessor: (originalRow, rowIndex) => (
           <div>
               <button onClick={() => handleEdit(originalRow)}>Edit</button>
               <button onClick={() => handleDelete(originalRow)}>Delete</button>
           </div>
        ),
        id: 'action',
      },
```